# Best practice to display values after submitting form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am quite new to ASP.NET and MVC and I'm currently trying the following:

- Model: Properties of the form
- View: Display a form to the user
- Controller:

  - Action: Do something
  - Go back to initial view and display values to user

With normal html I got this to work. With razor syntax I so far did not manage to re-display the values after the form was submitted.

My model:

```
namespace MyModels
{
  public class SubmitTicketFormModel
  {
     [DisplayName("First Name")]
     public string _firstName { get; set; }

     [DisplayName("Last Name")]
     public string _lastName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My View:

```
@model MyModels.SubmitTicketFormModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SubmitTicketView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Request</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTicketAction", "SubmitTicketContoller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._firstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._firstName, new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._lastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._lastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Post comment" />
}


<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model._firstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model._lastName
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
    public class SubmitTicketController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SubmitTicketView()
        {
            var TicketInstance = new SubmitTicketFormModel();
            return View(TicketInstance);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitTicketAction(SubmitTicketFormModel model)  
        {
            var NewTicketInstance = new SubmitTicketFormModel()
            {
                _firstName = model._firstName,
                _lastName = model._lastName
            };

            return View(NewTicketInstance);

        }
     }

 }
```

Can you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add some more information? Like some screenshots of functionalities? Are you trying to Add data to database and then show the value in the grid (table)? Then in that case you have to redirect to initial view using `RedirectToAction` method.

Comment: Can you add the name of your view and the name of the folder?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. The view is under Views -> SubmitTicket -> SubmitTicketView.cshtml. What I want to achieve in the end is to make a Jira API call to submit a new ticket, but as you can see I'm still far away from achieving that. Therefore I would like to do it step-by-step and the first step would be that the values the user submitted are displayed in the view again after submitting. Later on I am going to use these values for the API call. At the moment I don't want to add data to a DB. So for now just 1. Submit form 2. Display submitted values in view.

Comment: Rename `public ActionResult SubmitTicketAction` to public ActionResult SubmitTicketView` (and of course update the name the same way in your HTML.BeginForm statement) and you should be good to go. You didn't say what is going wrong precisely, but I think it might be because there is no view file associated with SubmitTicketAction.

Comment: That should work I think, but I'm not sure it's a great design. For one thing, as well as adding details to your table it will repopulate your form as well, so people could easily end up submitting the same data twice. At the very least it would be confusing. Also, how are people supposed to find this info again later if they come back to the site? The normal pattern would be to save the data, and then redirect the user to a "details" page using the saved ID as a querystring parameter - that URL can then be re-used anytime to see the same item

Comment: P.s. you really don't need to create the NewTicketInstance object. All you're doing is creating an identical copy, without adding or changing anything. You could just do `return View(model);` directly.

Comment: Hi ADyson, I agree that this is a bad design pattern and it's really just for testing purposes. The normal pattern you described is the one we are aiming for when it comes to the actual functionality, so submitting ticket and then displaying the ticket on a details page. I will try what you suggested once I'm back at my dev computer, thanks already for the useful hints. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same View to render after the user clicks on submit button, then I guess you don't want that @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTicketAction", "SubmitTicketContoller", FormMethod.Post)) in the UI to show up again. Only the values of first name and last name in your view of which you've written your logic down in your view.
In that case, you can just pass a ViewBag in your view from controller which will help your View understand whether it has to show the input form or display user's entered data.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitTicketAction(SubmitTicketFormModel model)  
        {
            var NewTicketInstance = new SubmitTicketFormModel()
            {
                _firstName = model._firstName,
                _lastName = model._lastName
            };
            ViewBag.Check = "true";
            return View(ViewName , modelname);

        }
```

And then in your view,

```
@model MyModels.SubmitTicketFormModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SubmitTicketView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@if(ViewBag.Check != null)
{
<h1>Request</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTicketAction", "SubmitTicketContoller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._firstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._firstName, new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._lastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._lastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Post comment" />
}
}
else
{

<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model._firstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model._lastName
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach that I will try out, thanks a lot.

Comment: I wanted to ask in comment whether you want to display data after submitting in the same view itself or will it be okay to use a different view. And also whether you want that form to be displayed again if you want to use the same view. But since I didn't had enough reputation to comment, so had to post an answer itself : P.

Comment: Haha. So to answer the question, another view would also be possible and is probably the better design approach, I guess ? In general I would like to stick as close as possible to a best practice approach.

Comment: Yes. If you just want to show the data what user has submitted not in the form itself, then it would be nice to use a different view. And there are already templates available for create, edit , view pages. All you have to do is right click on your submitticketaction method, click on add view, and then choose mvc view template, and choose your model from the dropdown. Then it will create a View which you can customize afterwards. If you're unfamiliar with this approach, you can just google it how to add MVC view template with passing modal and you'll get your job done.

Comment: Thanks to your and ADysons' tipps, I am now happy with the first step. I added a details page with right clicking on the action (quite convenient way, thanks).  In the HttpPost-Action I changed the code to "return View("Details",model);" .  The details page now contains the template code plus the table that I had on my initial view to display the submitted values. Next step will be use the submitted variables to make a Jira API call. Design-wise what would you suggest? Make the API call within the existing action or create a new action that gets called by the existing action?

Comment: Well i don't know that much but it depends. What operation do you want to perform with that API? Get or Post? And also after making the call, if you just want to return to the same page (here details page), with some data returned from the API, then you can do Ajax calling which has a pretty simple syntax.

Comment: I would like to create a Jira issue and then display it afterwards, so a combination of both, I guess. This is the SDK/API https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home. When you scroll down you can see examples for creating an issue an retrieving issues.

Comment: Is there any authentication mechanism that needs to be done to read/write with your JIRA Api? And if yes, then how will you be authenticating it?

Comment: The Jira connection and authentication luckily already works and we manage to create a new issue in Jira according to the documentation bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home. so basically something like this just with custom fields: 

var issue = jira.CreateIssue("My Project");
issue.Type = "Bug";
issue.Priority = "Major";
issue.Summary = "Issue Summary";

await issue.SaveChangesAsync();

The question now is, how can I reuse the values that are returned to display the newly created issue?

Comment: Well we want to show the data returned from the api after creating your new issue to the same display page, than Ajax call is a much better option. But if you want to show it in a different page, then we can do ActionMethod call which will return a new View. Both the methods will be pretty simple. Could you please tell me how would you like to proceed from one of the above?